# Я не один из трёх мушкетёров

Tags: ономастика

Как правильно оформить здесь *трёх мушкетёров*, если имеются в виду не какие-то абстрактные три мушкетёра, а три всем известных персонажа из романа Дюма? Ведь вроде же надо как-то выделить данных трёх мушкетёров из общего ряда мушкетёров, или можно не выделять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня мнение, диаметрально противоположное Alex_ander'у. Я даже не сразу сообразил, о чем речь, а каком "выделении" ожно говорить.

Не думаю, что здесь надо как-то специально выделять. "Три мушкетера" Дюма настолько на слуху всех, что это первое и единственное, о чем тут думаешь. Да еще конструкция фразы ("один из") такова, что ни о чем другом просто думать не хочется. Вот если бы имелись какие-то другие мушкетёры, то пришлось бы кинуть какой-то наводящий мостик.

Но если какие-то сомнения, напишите *"из трех королевских мушкетеров", "тех самых трех..."* - и т. п. Пунктуационным и/или дизайнерским выделением тут все равно ничего не добьётесь.

Comment: Дело в том, что из контекста будет понятно, что речь идёт именно о трёх персонажах романа Дюма. Вопрос в том, надо ли в этой конкретной фразе (которая будет стоять в соответствующем контексте) оформлять "трёх мушкетёров" как имя собственное (например, вот так: "Я не один из Трёх мушкетёров"), или ничего выделять не нужно. Я в принципе согласен с Вашим ответом, но есть сомнения, поскольку это всё-таки не какие-то абстрактные три мушкетёра, а вполне конкретные.

Comment: *Дело в том, что из контекста будет понятно, * - тогда в чем вообще вопрос, если из контекста понятно? Если он чисто насчет правил, то правила никак не регламентируют необходимость выделения. Вот если бы вы  хотели показать, что не один из трех героев-мушкетёров, а именно из книги с таким названием, то тогда и были бы кавычки и заглавная. Но тут-то речь идет именно о мушкетёрах, а не о книге, насколько понимаю.

Comment: Я просто не хочу приводить контекст, чтобы не засорять форум, но в этом контексте сами мушкетёры не упоминаются, приведённая фраза - первая и последняя, где они непосредственно упоминаются... Хорошо, я понял, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку говорящий жив и активно дистанцируется от названных лиц, как ни выделяйте, прочитавший будет искать охранное ОАО "Три мушкетёра", артгруппу или что-нибудь подобное. Чтобы такое утверждение поняли как метафору, лучше добавить уточняющие слова, например:

> Я не вхожу в число известных всем (пресловутых, прославленных,
>   печально известных - в зависимости от сравнительной самооценки) трёх
>   мушкетёров.

Кроме того, стилистически неудачна конструкция "я (не) один из вас/них/кого-то" (меня двое?) - она иногда проникает в русский язык из переводов с английского. Лучше ориентироваться на Грибоедова: "... (есть тьма искусников,) *я не из их числа"*.